# Setting a Google+ vanity URL like plus.google.com/me

Tags: google, google-plus, url-shortening

Where can I set a vanity URL for my Google+ profile? Ideally I would like to be able to have my current `profiles.google.com` URL brought over in case Google decide the profiles are now valid for Google Plus.

I've seen services such as gplus.to and plus.ly but neither are official means.

From my searches I also don't think it's currently available (infered from the lack of results).

I could have it like `profiles.google.com/me` (which you could choose here: http://www.google.com/profiles/me/editprofile?edit=t#about). But this link does not work anymore (IMHO because profiles.google.com is being integrated into Google+)

Comment: My [profiles link](https://profiles.google.com/jleedev) still works.

Comment: @jleedev: Yes, and you did it when the above link was valid (And it redirect to your G+ profile)

Comment: G+ is now rolling out vanity URLs [How can I get Custom Vanity Google plus URLs?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/51294)

Answer (score 5):

I think this might change when Google Profiles and Google+ are fully integrated.
As for now, the best option I've seen is using [gplus.to](http://gplus.to), where you can manually choose your link in the form `http://gplus.to/yourname`.
It works quite well, but it should be noted that they are NOT connected to Google in any way. This is some sort of inofficial workaround for people like you and me.

Answer (score 3):

Another recent entry into this market is [Gooplus.me](http://www.facebookgoogleplus.com/gooplus-me-get-your-own-google-plus-vanity-url/)

Their URLs are of the form `http://gooplus.me/yourname`.

I have no connection with this site.