# How can I get Custom Vanity Google plus URLs?

Tags: google-plus

I see that Google and Blogger and maybe other have a customized Google Plus URL.

Ex:

- http://plus.google.com/+google/posts
- http://plus.google.com/+blogger/posts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google is only beginning to roll out these vanity URLs. Currently, only a few thousand verified and well known people and brands have it, although they will be adding more over time. See [this post](https://plus.google.com/107117483540235115863/posts/87UHpXFb64b) for (not much) more information.

In the meantime, you should be able to create a redirect from your own website to your profile. (It may be argued that this is a better solution, even.) You can also setup a [Google+ Badge](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/) to let visitors to your website go to your profile or follow you directly from your site.

Comment: In the meantime there are a few services that let you do URL shortening. http://gplus.to is onesuch.

Comment: @Prisoner: Thank you! I was looking for a post like that but i didn't found it anywhere.

Comment: @Al Everett: I am already using gplus.to :) but i was looking for a official way to do that. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

Google+ is now [rolling out vanity URLs](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340?hl=en-GB&topic=2400106), provided you meet the eligibility requirements

> Before you can get a custom URL, your account needs to be in good
>   standing and meet the following requirements:
>
> - Eligibility for People:
>
>   - 10 or more followers
>   - Your account is 30 days old or more
>   - A profile photo
> - Eligibility for Local Google+ pages: Must be a verified local business
> - Eligibility for Non-local Google+ pages: [Must be linked to a website](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1713826?hl=en)
>
> #### Getting your custom URL through Google+
>
> If you meet the above criteria, you'll see a notification at the top
>   of your Google+ page or Profile.
>
> - Click on the Get a custom URL button to get started.
>
>   - Alternatively, from the "About" tab on your Profile, click on the "Claim" link located under your Google+ URL.
> - You'll see the URL for which you're approved. You may see more than one option. In this case, select the one that you like best. You may
>     also be asked to add a few numbers or letters to make the custom URL
>     unique to you.
> - Tick the box to agree to the Terms of Service.
> - Click on Change URL.
> - You may be asked to verify your account by mobile phone number. A box will pop up asking you to do so. If you have a verified phone
>     number, skip to step 6.   a. Enter your mobile phone number.   b. Tick
>     the box to make it easier for people who have your phone number to
>     find you on Google services.   c. Check your phone for the code that
>     was sent to you.   d. Enter that code in the box.   e. Click on
>     Verify.
> - Once approved, this URL will be linked to your Google+ page or Profile, so make sure that everything is exactly the way you want it.
>     Once your URL has been approved, you can't request to change it. When
>     you're sure, click on Confirm.