# How can I change the URL of my Google+ account?

Tags: google-plus, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Custom Vanity Google plus URLs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30806/how-can-i-get-custom-vanity-google-plus-urls)

I just want to add my own name to that URL instead of its(Google+'s) default boring alphanumerical codes......

Comment: [**This link**](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340?hl=en) may still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible for *everyone* to have their own vanity URL for Google+. Right now they're rolling it out slowly to verified people and well-known brands.

[source](https://plus.google.com/+SaurabhSharma/posts/9QTA8rQMNQ1)

There is at least one third party app that will give you a personalized url (but not an official one): `http://gplus.to/`

Disclosure: I'm not affiliated with `gplus.to` in any way except being a user.

Answer (score 1):

They began roll out of custom vanity user URL's in August this year. Several articles on this have stated the initial roll out will be for celebrities and brands. I don't believe it is possible yet. I suspect this to be available in a couple months based on other Google+ roll outs.

[Article on vanity URLs.](http://techcrunch.com/2012/08/23/google-starts-pre-approving-more-google-vanity-urls/)

Comment: lets hope not. Vanity URLs would be a serious Charlie Foxtrot. There are better ways.