# How can I get a custom Google Plus profile URL using the new Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, url

I have a Google Plus personal profile, and I want to get a custom URL for it. I meet all of the requirements for getting a custom URL:

> You have ten or more followers (people who have added you to their circles)
>
> Your account is at least 30 days old
>
> Your profile has a profile photo
>
> Your account is in good standing

The instructions from the [Google Support page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2676340?hl=en) are outdated, as the layout of Google Plus has changed and the pages it references no longer exist.

The answers in [this Stack Exchange post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/30806/how-can-i-get-custom-vanity-google-plus-urls) are similarly outdated, and mostly address brand URLs which have a different signup process than profile URLs.

How can I get a custom URL for my Google Plus profile?

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an option to create a custom URL in the new Google+. For now you may need to switch back to the Classic Google+ to do it and then switch back to the new one.